# Validation Not Working – Conditionally require rich text field

Tags: validation, validation-rule

written a validation to check if a Pan Card checkbox is true,then Pan Card image must be mandatory to fill in rich text area.But it is not Working

```
AND
(
$RecordType.Name = 'Channel Partner', 
OM_PAN_Card_Submitted__c = true,
NOT(CONTAINS(OM_PAN_Card_No__c,"Image" ))
)
```

Comment: How is it "not working"? Does it fire when it should not, or does it not fire when it should?

Comment: What if you try using $RecordType.DeveloperName = "Channel_Partner" instead or whatever the dev name for that Rec type is?

Comment: It's not at all firing. it lets me save the image even if checkbox is true. and i even tried using developer name

Comment: AND 
( 
$RecordType.DeveloperName = "Channel_Partner", 
OM_PAN_Card_Submitted__c = true, 
NOT(CONTAINS(OM_PAN_Card_No__c,"Image" )) 
)

Comment: `CONTAINS` is case sensitive so does `OM_PAN_Card_No__c` actually have `image` rather than `Image`?

Comment: yes. after uploading the image and if you debug the contents of the field ,you will get it in the format :"<img alt="User-added image" src="https://omkar--Staging--c.cs5.content.force.com/servlet/rtaImage?eid=001O0000017TScf&amp;feoid=00NO0000002QtSC&amp;refid=0EMO0000000D5Yq"></img>"

Comment: and also tried using both "image" and "Image" ..